# Access Denied in PHP Cron job for Only LOAD operation

Tags: php, mysql, permission-denied

This is no longer a problem.... see below at end.

I am getting the following MySQL error while trying to LOAD a table from a file in a CRON job.
*Access denied for user 'laurel'@'localhost' (using password: YES)*

This is the LOAD statement:

```
$LoadQuery="load data local infile 'http://example.com/~laurel/csvfiles/handicaps.csv' 
            into TABLE handicap fields terminated by ','";
```

(the IP address is actually being used in the path instead of example.com)
The LOAD works when I run it within the website, from the URL line and from phpMyAdmin. I can do everything else in the CRON job with this user including inserting to a table and deleting a table. Everything except LOAD. When I try running it without the 'local' coded I get the same access error. And, without 'local' in the statement I receive the Access Error when running the query from the website and from phpMyAdmin. It works from the website and from phpMyAdmin only when 'local' is included.

When I look at the permissions for this user from the cPanel ALL PRIVILEGES, as well as the following individual priveleges are checked:

```
 ALL PRIVILEGES
 ALTER   CREATE
 CREATE ROUTINE  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES
 CREATE VIEW     DELETE
 DROP    EXECUTE
 INDEX   INSERT
 LOCK TABLES     REFERENCES
 SELECT  SHOW VIEW
 TRIGGER     UPDATE
```

What am I missing?  Why isn't this user able to do a LOAD function? 
Thank you in advance for your help

---

**This is no longer a problem. I made the following change to the LOAD statement and it worked:
$LoadQuery="load data local infile \"../csvfiles/handicaps.csv\" into TABLE handicap fields terminated by ','";**

Comment: access denied means the user cannot connect to the database.. Start by verifying username, password, hostname and database.

Comment: See manual, [LOAD DATA INFILE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html): *The LOCAL keyword affects expected location of the file and error handling, as described later. **LOCAL works only if your server and your client both have been configured to permit it.** For example, if mysqld was started with --local-infile=0, LOCAL does not work.* And the FILE privilege isn't granted, so LOAD DATA INFILE gives the access error message you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you for your input. This is no longer a problem. I made the following change to the LOAD statement and it worked: $LoadQuery="load data local infile \"../csvfiles/handicaps.csv\" into TABLE handicap fields terminated by ','";

Comment: @John Post it as an answer and mark it as accepted, so that future users may be able to view the solution easier.

Answer (score 0):

This is no longer a problem.

I made the following change to the LOAD statement and it worked: $LoadQuery="load data local infile \"../csvfiles/handicaps.csv\" into TABLE handicap fields terminated by ','";

Comment: John can you click the checkmark on this as the accepted answer so others can reference this solution in other questions. Thanks.