# CRON with CPanel

Tags: mysql, cron, cpanel

I would like to execute an SQL query via CRON Cpanel.

Here is the COMMAND:

```
mysql --user=MYUSERNAME --password=MYPASSWORD --database=MYDATABASE \
    --execute="LOAD DATA INFILE '/usr/local/bin/php/home/MYFILE.csv' INTO TABLE MYDATABASE.MYTABLE charset 'utf8' FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 2 LINES".
```

Here is the error message I get:

> ERROR 1045 (28000) at line 1: Access denied for user 'MYUSERNAME'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Please use code syntax in your question. The answer is your username does not have the right permissions to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have solved this issue thanks to a previous post: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25040589/access-denied-in-php-cron-job-for-only-load-operation/25065161#25065161.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several attempts, I found the answer: I had to put \" before the path on the CRON command line. I hope this will be useful for anyone else.

```
mysql --user=MYUSERNAME --password=MYPASSWORD --database=MYDATABASE --execute="LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE \"/home/MYFILE.csv\" INTO MYDATABASE.MYTABLE FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 2 LINES“
```

Comment: This seems to be different to the statement in your question, which uses single quotes for the `INFILE` parameter?

Comment: Oh right, I see - how odd that it doesn't work with single quotes. Fair enough, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to grant MYUSERNAME permissions to MYDATABASE.

If you are using cPanel, go to the Databases tool and create MYUSERNAME, then grant it permission to access MYDATABASE.

Many time cPanel prefixes both the user and database names with the account name, so you may need to adjust the command to be:

mysql -u account_MYUSERNAME account_MYDATABASE (...)

Be sure to grant the user FILE privileges - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_file

Comment: Hi Shawn and user2182349: I checked again and the user does have the permission (special privileges) to access the database.

Comment: What privileges have been granted?

Comment: All privileges. I have the same pb than here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25040589/access-denied-in-php-cron-job-for-only-load-operation/25065161#25065161Except the solution does not work for me.